# Angular make reducer from an Array

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, rxjs

I understand that for count an array in Angular with **rxjs** I use reduce, for example if I want count : `[{id: 1, items: [10, 20, 30]}]` I use the following code:

```
const item = from([{id: 1, items: [10, 20, 30]}]);
item.pipe(
  map(actions => actions.items),
  mergeAll(),
  reduce((acc, i) => acc + i, 0)
).subscribe(p => console.log('Print 60: ', p));
```

The questions is How get make a reducer in the following array:

```
const items = [
{
  id: 1,
  boxing: [1, 2, 2]
},
{
  id: 2,
  boxing: [10, 10, 20]
}];
```

result expected:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  boxing: 5
},
{
  id: 2,
  boxing: 40
}]
```

I will appreciate your help

Comment: Any reason you're doing it inside of an rxjs stream? It seems since you have an array, you can just use the native .reduce function.

Comment: Hi jesse, no special reason, but the idea is to do it with rxjs. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily do this with javascript by using `reduce` and `map` as

```js
const items = [
     {id: 1, boxing: [1, 2, 2]},
     {id: 2, boxing: [10, 10, 20]}
];

let reducedItems = items.map(val => {
  return {
    id: val.id,
    boxing: val.boxing.reduce((a, i) => a + i)
   }
});

console.log(reducedItems);
```

Comment: Alright @Jesse. I think you should post it as an answer

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-cxhrt9
Just a small example applying @Saksham example inside the pipe map()

Answer (score 1):

One approach can be this.

```
from(items).pipe(
  mergeMap((data) => from(data['boxing']).pipe(
    reduce((acc, x) => acc + x),
    map((val) => { data['boxing'] = val; return data })
  )),
  toArray()
).subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
```